# Ros launch gets stuck on robot in 5G network

Tags: ros

I am trying to set up a Ros Network between a Robot (Clearpath AGV) and a Multi-access edge computing device (MEC) via 5G. I start roscore on the MEC and launch some nodes there. Everything works fine, but when **when starting any launch file on robot side they get stuck as if waiting for the roscore** (with and without --wait). This happens also for a simple static_transform_publisher launch. Please find logs of an example launch and the terminal output when I interrupt via keyboard below

The Ros Network seems to be fully established since:

- Rostopic list/echo/info works for topics I publish to both ways
- Rosrun works on Robot and MEC
- Various networking tools (Netcat,...) show that all registered ports are open both ways

More details:

- Working with docker with kinetic installed.
- Containers run in host network mode
- ROS_MASTER_URI is set to the MECs IP
- ROS_IP on the robot is set to its own IP
- Both IPs are pingable from either machine.

Any help is appreciated!

Logs:

```
[roslaunch][INFO] 2020-10-05 15:35:44,123: starting in server mode
[roslaunch.parent][INFO] 2020-10-05 15:35:44,123: starting roslaunch parent run
[roslaunch][INFO] 2020-10-05 15:35:44,123: loading roscore config file /opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros/roscore.xml
[roslaunch] [INFO] 2020-10-05 15:35:44,365: Added core node of type [rosout/rosout] in namespace [/]
[roslaunch.config][INFO] 2020-10-05 15:35:44,365: loading config file /root/catkin_ws/src/realsense-ro
s/realsense2_camera/launch/rs_camera. launch
[roslaunch] [INFO] 2020-10-05 15:35:44,391: Added node of type [nodelet/nodelet] in namespace [/camera/]
[roslaunch] [INFO] 2020-10-05 15:35:44,397: Added node of type [nodelet/nodelet] in namespace [/camera/]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2020-10-05 15:35:44,397: ... selected machine [] for node of type [nodelet/nodelet]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2020-10-05 15:35:44,397: ... selected machine [] for node of type [nodelet/nodelet]
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2020-10-05 15:35:44,400: start_process_ monitor: creating ProcessMonitor
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2020-10-05 15:35:44,400: created process monitor <ProcessMonitor(ProcessMonitor
-1, initial daemon)>
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2020-10-05 15:35:44,400: start_process_ monitor: ProcessMonitor started
[roslaunch.parent][INFO] 2020-10-05 15:35:44,400: starting parent XML-RPC server
[roslaunch.server][INFO] 2020-10-05 15:35:44,400: starting roslaunch XML-RPC server
[roslaunch.server][INFO] 2020-10-05 15:35:44,400: waiting for roslaunch XML-RPC server to initialize
[xmlrpc] [INFO] 2020-10-05 15:35:44,400: XML-RPC server binding to 0.0.0.0:0
[xmlrpc] [INFO] 2020-10-05 15:35:44,401: Started XML-RPC server [http://10.0.91.105:41500/ ]
[xmlrpc] [INFO] 2020-10-05 15:35:44,401: xml rpc node: starting XML-RPC server
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2020-10-05 15:35:50,254: ProcessMonitor.shutdown <ProcessMonitor (ProcessMonitor
-1, started daemon 140017957467904)>
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2020-10-05 15:35:50,308: ProcessMonitor. post_run <ProcessMonitor(ProcessMonito
r-1, started daemon 140017957467904)>
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2020-10-05 15:35:50,308: ProcessMonitor. post_run <ProcessMonitor(ProcessMonito
r-1, started daemon 140017957467904)>: remaining procs are []
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2020-10-05 15:35:50,309: ProcessMonitor exit: cleaning up data structures and signals
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2020-10-05 15:35:50,310: ProcessMonitor exit: pmon has shutdown
[rospy.core][INFO] 2020-10-05 15:35:50,312: signal_shutdown [atexit]
```

Terminal output:

```
root@CPR-R100-0067:~/catkin_ws# roslaunch realsense2_camera rs_camera. launch
«.. logging to /root/.ros/log/9cbf306c -0718-11eb-b8a5- fa163ea8af66/roslaunch-CPR-R100- 0067-954. log
Checking log directory for disk usage. 
This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interruptDone checking log file disk usage. 
Usage is <1GB.
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
File "“/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/roslaunch”, line 35, in <module>roslaunch.main()
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__ init__.py", line 308, in mainp.start()
File "“/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py”, line 268, in startself._start_infrastructure()
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", Line 226, in _start_infrastructureself.start_server()
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 177, in start_serverself.server.start()
File "“/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/server.py", line 376, in startcode, msg, val = ServerProxy(self.urt).get_pid()
File “/usc/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1243, tn _ callreturn self.__send(self.name, args)
File "“/usc/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1602, in _ requestverbose=self. verbose
File "“/usc/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1283, in requestreturn self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
File "“/usc/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1311, tn single_requestself.send_content(h, request_body)
File "“/usc/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1459, tn send_contentconnection.endheaders(request_body)
File "“/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py”, line 1082, in endheadersself._send_output(message_body)
File "“/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py”, Line 909, in _send_outputself.send(msg)
File "“/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 871, in sendself .connect()
File "“/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py”, Line 848, in connectself.timeout, self.source_address)
File "“/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 566, in create_connectionsock.connect(sa)
File "“/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in methreturn getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Just to double-check: does `rostopic echo /rosout` work on the robot?

Comment: Hello Christian, yes the robot can echo /rosout.